# Foreach iterate through list of strings and compare it to open forms

Tags: c#, forms

So i'm working on a chat system. I want to iterate through the open forms, and check it versus  a list of strings (form.text != s). And if it doesn't find an open form that is equal to the person's name, then it opens a new instance of it. My issue is, is that it's not catching if the forms open or not. It just automatically throws it in the list of forms to be opened. I can't figure out why either, as it's detecting that the form IS open by that text, but still adding them to the list and opening a new form. Any help?

```
                    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
                    foreach (Form f in fc)
                    {
                        if (f.Text != iRow["Sender"].ToString())
                        {
                            if (!people.Contains(iRow["Sender"].ToString()))
                            {
                                people.Add(iRow["Sender"].ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        else if (f.Text == iRow["Sender"].ToString())
                        {
                            f.BringToFront();
                        }
                    }




                    foreach (string s in people)
                    {

                        ChatBox chat = new ChatBox();
                        Connection.ConnectionStrings.chatopen = s;
                        chat.Text = s;
                        chat.Show();
                        chat.BringToFront();
                        ChatBox.sound.playsound.Play();


                    }


                people.Clear();
```

Comment: Check the contents of people before you start your first foreach, make sure it is empty. Also make sure the case of your string matches the case of your Forms.Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this.

Scan each form looking for the sender, if you don't find that name in any of the forms open a new chatbox with that sender. If you do find it then just focus on that chat box.

```
// Has sender been found
var found = false;

// get the sender ???
var sender = iRow["Sender"].ToString();

FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
foreach (Form f in fc)
{
    // does the form text match our sender 
    if (f.Text == sender)
    {
        f.BringToFront();
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

// if we did not find a form matching the sender
if ( !found )
{
    ChatBox chat = new ChatBox();
    Connection.ConnectionStrings.chatopen = sender;
    chat.Text = sender;
    chat.Show();
    chat.BringToFront();
    ChatBox.sound.playsound.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is iRow["Sender"]?

Maybe iRow["Sender"] take some unexpected value.

In another condition, you should make sure the value field of f.Text is just the value field of iRow["Sender"].ToString()

Comment: iRow is the datarow. Sender was just the value of a column. It's taking the value correctly, when I insert break points it's giving the correct values, and even showing that they are equal but still adding it none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that  might help after seeing your code

1 - You are clearing people collection at bottom which enable the condition

```
                  if (f.Text != iRow["Sender"].ToString())
                    {
                        if (!people.Contains(iRow["Sender"].ToString()))
                        {
                            people.Add(iRow["Sender"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
```

in some scenario , i am not aware of your code but that can possible.

2- To activate the form , you can use the following code

```
        appform.Activate();
        appform.Show();
```